# webview showing white bar on right side

Tags: android

I am giving the following method call to my webview client embedded in my layout
`wv.loadData("<html><body bgcolor=\"Black\"></body></html>","text/html", "utf-8");`

when i run this on the device, it shows a white vertical bar on the right side. I fixed the white thing by using `webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);` but i want to remove it completely

Following is my layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
    <WebView android:id="@+id/wv1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: could you shows us the xml of the layout you are using?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use the following to hide but not remove the functionality of the scrollbar.  The layout margin adjustment is a nasty work-around.

`//webview being your WebView object reference.
webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);`

Comment: A side note to this.  I have no idea why, but setting this in the XML file rather than in the Java code did not work for me.

Comment: @rushinge Completely agree that this doesn't work when set using XML. Here is a logged Android defect http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17293&q=scrollbarStyle&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: You will usually prefer **WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY**. That way the scrollbar will just show when you scroll the view. This is the default behaviour in newer platforms, but not on the old ones (at least not up to API level 11).

Answer (score 9):

I would set margin: 0 and padding: 0 inside the . You could do something like

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
```

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the "best" answer but it worked for me.

```
<WebView android:layout_marginRight="-7dip" />
```

Let me know if there is something better because this feels hackish to me.

Comment: I was right, it is hackish.  Please see Chris Danielson's solution above.

Comment: I actually used something similar to this, but got unexpected behaviour across different devices. Do not use this.

Answer (score 1):

My app has a selectable night-mode which switches to white on black.  The central View is a  WebView displaying text.

For night-mode I used an extra css file that showed white text on a black backbround but users complained about the white scrollbar on the right.  So I had much the same problem as outlined above.  However, I needed to switch in and out of night-mode programatically at runtime but I didn't want merely to hide the scrollbars.

The simple solution I used was:

```
if (isNightMode()) {
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
} else {
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Setting the backgroundColor of the WebView affected the scrollbars as required.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting white bars on the left and right side where the webview was matching the parent height and width in the XML file. But the issue I found was a line of code missing on the Java class file.

Adding this fixed the issue for me.

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```