# Android Fullscreen Webapp Backend Application

Tags: android, web-applications, fullscreen

I've created a WebView-based application according to http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Although I did exactly what was written, including p.5, the application is not full-screen.

> While you're in the manifest, give some more space for web pages by
>   removing the title bar, with the "NoTitleBar" theme:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps"
android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

The full code of the manifest is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mydomain.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The main.xml file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

I've tested the application in both emulator (2.2) and a real device (2.3), the project platform is 2.2.

The result is presented here (the real device looks similar):

[image]

What's wrong with my app, why does the title bar appear and what's the right bar?

Regards,

**UPDATE**

This question partially duplicates this one (the right bar):
[webview showing white bar on right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279978/webview-showing-white-bar-on-right-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you in the onCreate()-method:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); -- I've commented it out, since it crashed the app. The app is full-screen now, thank you.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, I didn't test this snippet, but if it works fine now, I'm content. :)

Comment: Hm... the app is full-screen, but the left bar is still there. What can it be? I guess, the WebView component is black, as the HTML background color is set to 0 and I don't see the bar in any other browser (Chrome, FF, Chromium, Safari, Mobile Safari). I have no ideas how to debug this. After VS, Eclipse and Android look unfamiliar and strange.

Comment: SO rules! ^) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279978/webview-showing-white-bar-on-right-side

Comment: uhmm.... I will try to find out. ;) Don't know if it's a problem of the manifest.xml or the webView. EDIT: Oh, yeah just perfect :)

Comment: Can someone explain this? What is the meaning of setting the style of the app and when do you - in addition? - also need to request no title and fullscreen in the ACtivities' onCreate?